# Settings Codeigniter 3 HMVC with tank auth

Tags: authentication, codeigniter-3, hmvc, tankauth, codeigniter-hmvc

I'm trying to install Auth Tank in CodeIgniter in HMVC but without success.
I did the following:

- I created the tables in the database;
- I put the folders (config, controllers, helpers, language, libraries, models, views) within `modules/auth/`;
- In `application/config/routes.php` I added the route to the Auth Tank: `$Route["auth"] = "auth/login";`;
- In Controller `auth.php` I changed  `$this->lang->load('tank_auth');`  to  `$this->lang->load('auth/tank_auth');`
- I changed the controller files to extends MY_Controller (that extends MX_Controller)

After this continues this error:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: RuntimeException
>
> Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Login_attempts
>
> Filename:
>   /home/danineto/public_html/ide/workspace/spin/system/core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 344
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /home/danineto/public_html/ide/workspace/spin/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
>   Line: 213 Function: model
>
> File:
>   /home/danineto/public_html/ide/workspace/spin/application/modules/auth/libraries/Tank_auth.php
>   Line: 601 Function: model
>
> File:
>   /home/danineto/public_html/ide/workspace/spin/application/modules/auth/controllers/Auth.php Line: 57 Function: is_max_login_attempts_exceeded
>
> File: /home/danineto/public_html/ide/workspace/spin/index.php Line:
>   315 Function: require_once

Has anyone implemented this library that can help me?

Thank you